# Why is the exponential function I'm attempting to graph returning a stopping point?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I am trying to graph $\displaystyle {y=10^{-350}e^x}$ on desmos. However, this is returning a straight line with a stopping point at (709.783,0).

Is this a normal trait of very small exponentials that I haven't come across? Or is it simply the limits of desmos' software?

Thanks,
Ben

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hf1kx6mtyf

(There's the graph. Feel free to ignore the data points.)

Comment: $10^{-350}$ is so incredibly small I'd assume it's a limitation of the software. It's being displayed as 0 because Desmos rounds to 3 or so decimal places IIRC.

Comment: @AndrewLi Okay, that's what my teacher said, too, but he wasn't sure, so I wanted to check. Thank-you!

Comment: I'm curious–why wouldn't your teacher be sure? An exponential function is an exponential function and will behave like one. An exponential function doesn't fail to grow exponentially just because its y-intercept is extremely small.

Comment: @BenQuick Take the natural log of both sides, and rearrange the terms. What you get is [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7hjxnmr6wr) which still behaves like an exponential program.

Comment: @AndrewLi No, that makes sense. I only talked to him about it for 5 minutes, so I probably wasn't clear in communicating what was going on.

Comment: @TobyMak Okay, thank-you!

Comment: Damn, I meant function. Must have been thinking about coding...

Comment: @TobyMak Lol, that's alright. You're message was still received.

Comment: @AndrewLi People like you and others on math.stackexchange should be teachers, I don't have high expectations from teachers based off personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Desmos uses the double-precision IEEE-754 encoding for the numbers for its calculations. This is the implementation of the data type known as a `double` in languages such as Java and C++ on (almost?) all modern computers.

The largest possible number that can be represented in double-precision IEEE-754 is $(2 - 2^{-52})\times 2^{1023} \approx 1.8 \times 10^{308}.$
Note that $\ln((2 - 2^{-52})\times 2^{1023}) \approx 709.7827,$
so $e^{709.783}$ is too large to be represented in this format,
whereas $e^{709.782}$ can be represented.

On the other hand, the smallest positive number that can be represented
in double-precision IEEE-754 is $2^{-1074} \approx 4.9 \times 10^{-324}.$
Since $10^{-350}$ is much smaller than that, it would be rounded to zero.

In order to evaluate $10^{-350} e^x$ using double-precision IEEE-754 numbers and arithmetic, if we do not do some clever symbolic manipulation but simply perform the operations literally written in that expression,
then we get zero times some real number
for all $x$ such that $e^x$ can be represented as a finite number in
double-precision IEEE-754 format,
and zero times infinity otherwise.
Zero times any real number is zero, and zero times infinity is considered
"not a number" in IEEE-754,
so the value of the expression is zero until $x$ gets too great for the expression to have any numeric value at all.
The switchover point is near $x = 709.783.$

If you graph $y=\left(10^{-175}\cdot e^{x/2}\right)^2,$
which is exactly the same function in pure mathematics,
Desmos shows something that looks like a proper exponential graph,
reaching the value $y=1$ at $x \approx 805.9$ and increasing
exponentially after that.